# How to use Apache Kafka in this use case

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to use kafka in the company project.
Now I use ejabberd to communicate with thousands of clients in Italy. Each client receives only the messages that have been created for him. Authentication is basic, with username and password.
I would like to replace ejabberd with kafka but I don't understand how to manage the authentication of thousands of clients.
The kafka producer will have to create a message only for a consumer, and other consumers will not have to read the messages.
If this is possible, is it also possible to configure client credentials by java code?

Thank